# How can I contribute to an Ubuntu package on Launchpad with an upstream on Github?

Tags: bug-reporting, launchpad, debugging, github, contributing

I recently reported a bug for which a fix already exists on GitHub (upstream), and I would like to cherry-pick such fix and submit it on Launchpad for review for focal 20.04. However, I couldn't find how to do it, especially considering the upstream is hosted on GitHub and not on Launchpad itself.

(The bug is quite disruptive, otherwise I wouldn't try to submit to a stable version)

- Bug link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel/+bug/1892245
- Upstream: https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel

Comment: Seems like you are looking for the [Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) process. You're already part of the way down that road; you already confirmed the fix in Groovy.